# iPhone 5s goes to airplane mode by itself

Tags: iphone, airplane-mode

How does my iPhone 5s get to airplane mode if I do not go into Settings and change it manually to airplane mode?

Comment: I am not aware of an instance that an iPhone would automatically disable its antenna's and go into Airplane Mode. I have a suspicion that it is a hardware problem or perhaps a low-level OS bug that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's better to take it to an apple service center..

Comment: I have an Iphone 5S 64g I have the same problem and have 8 service tickets open with Apple. No solution from them. The airplane mode comes on when using Polar Beat App. and Bose Soundsport inear headphones. I just updated to IOS 8.4 June 30 and used the Bose inear headphones with Polar beat and the airplane mode came on automatically. Yesterday I used the Apple earbuds and it did not come on. Which apps are open when it comes on and are you using any type of headphones.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the control center!

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the question, which was "How does it do it by itself?" not "How else can I do it?"

Comment: Since the OP mentions going into Settings to switch to airplane mode, it's possible the OP isn't aware of the swipe-up menu option and is hitting the icon by mistake. Additionally, it does *technically* answer the question due to the "if I do not go into settings" qualifier. 'Saying.